# Padding to an image and saving with Rust image crate corrupts image

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix, rust, padding

I am currently working on developing a convolutional neural network from scratch. Upon reaching the padding step, I ran into some weird issues. For reference, I'm using Rust's image crate and the nalgebra crate to handle the data.

First, I load my data:

```rs
pub fn get_pixel_matrix(image: &DynamicImage) -> Result<DMatrix<i16>, InvalidGrayscaleImageError> {
    match image {
        DynamicImage::ImageLuma8(gray_image) => {
            // Data is converted into i16 form so it can later be convolved against negative values. Note that converting
            // between u8 and i8 is not safe and may result in overflow. Therefore, i16 is used to guarantee that no data
            // is lost when convolving.
            Ok(DMatrix::from_row_iterator(
                gray_image.dimensions().0 as usize,
                gray_image.dimensions().1 as usize,
                gray_image.pixels().map(|p| p.0[0] as i16),
            ))
        },
        _ => Err(InvalidGrayscaleImageError), // custom error
    }
}
```

After getting the value from this match, I have tested *immediately* saving the data back directly from the matrix I populated as a `.png` to make sure nothing was breaking on nalgebra's end. It saved the data correctly and I could not see any source of corruption, so I'm assuming this function and nalgebra are working properly.

Afterwards I just pad it. The function below is not my ideal padding solution, but it's just for testing purposes. As of now I'm assuming the padding is just one on each side.

```rs
let img = ImageReader::open("images\\grass.png")?
    .decode()?
    .grayscale();

let matrix = get_pixel_matrix(&img).unwrap();
let matrix_shape = matrix.shape();

let mut m: DMatrix<i16> = DMatrix::zeros_generic(
    Dynamic::from_usize(matrix_shape.0 + 2),
    Dynamic::from_usize(matrix_shape.1 + 2),
);

// recreate self with new borders
// for now, assume offset is one
for cx in 1..(matrix_shape.0 + 1) {
    for cy in 1..(matrix_shape.1 + 1) {
        m[(cx, cy)] = matrix[(cx - 1, cy - 1)];
    }
}
```

The image below shows my intended results. I have verified that this works on matrices of much larger sizes.

[image: Matrix padding intended results]

Finally, I take this matrix of data and write it out to a file. The function below is what I've used to testing all of my matrix-to-file saving, and works *before* padding. However, once the padding is done, the image seems to be corrupted.

```rs
/// Convert a grayscale pixel value to 255 (white) if greater than 255. If less than 0,
/// set the pixel value to 0 (black). Otherwise, leave the pixel value as is.
fn normalize(i: i16) -> u8 {
    if i > 255 {
        255 as u8
    } else if i < 0 {
        0 as u8
    } else {
        i as u8
    }
}

/// Save an image buffer (matrix form) into a file
fn save(name: &str, matrix: Matrix<i16, Dynamic, Dynamic, VecStorage<i16, Dynamic, Dynamic>>) {
    // nalgebra matrix iterators are column-major, not row-major, but the ImageBuffer is expecting a row-major
    // collection. Transposing the matrix as of now is not the best for performance, but makes it easier to read
    // when saving the file for debugging.
    let buf: Vec<u8> = matrix.transpose().iter().map(|i| normalize(*i)).collect();
    image::save_buffer(
        name,
        &buf,
        matrix.shape().0 as u32,
        matrix.shape().1 as u32,
        image::ColorType::L8,
    )
    .unwrap();
}
```

The original photo (grass.png, 127x120 image):

[image: grass.png]

The grayscale photo that was saved both using the image object from `ImageReader` (top) and from the matrix representation (bottom):

[image: gray from image crate]

[image: get_pixel_matrix representation]

Finally, after the padding, this was the result of saving the data (129x122 image):

[image]

I have printed the entire matrix (and the vector I'm obtaining after transposing the matrix) and I can confirm that the top, bottom, left, and right edges are all zeros. However, if you zoom in to the final image, you can clearly see the top right and bottom left (strange symmetry there...) have non-black pixels. Also, the left and right sides have nearly no black pixels at all. And of course, the weird diagonal patterns of black pixels. I've confirmed that my `matrix.shape()` values I'm using in the save function are the right dimensions.

Sorry if this question was bloated, but I've been scratching my head at this for a few days now and frankly I feel like I've made some goofy mistake somewhere that my mind just won't let me see because I'm convinced I covered my bases.

Answer (score 1):

Of course as soon as I post to stackoverflow I find the answer myself...

Came down to a variety of nasty assumptions I made that I completely overlooked. nalgebra's indexing and `shape()` are based on linear algebra indexing (which makes sense).

Therefore, in order to access the element at x = 2, y = 3, I would need to index in with `matrix[(3, 2)]`, because this reads as third row, second column of the matrix. Same with shape, as the shape function returns `(rows, cols)`, but I thought it did the opposite.

Comment: The sort of diagonal artifacts you saw are characteristic of having written or read image data with the wrong width, or byte-length-per-row (in this case, only very slightly wrong). This can come up a lot, and recognizing them can be useful.